# Hide all elements that come after the nth element

Tags: jquery, html

After the 4th `<a>` element is found, how would I `.hide()` the rest? Below is the code I've written so far:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        if($('a').length >= 4) {
            window.alert('4 or more');
        }
    });
</script>

<a>test </a><br>
<a>fed </a><br>
<a>fdes </a><br>
<a>grr </a><br>
<a>rerf </a><br>
<a>dferf </a>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [:gt(index)](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector:

```
$('a:gt(3)').hide();
```

Or the faster [`slice`](http://api.jquery.com/slice/) function:

```
$('a').slice(4).hide();
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/PrFRP/)

> Because **:gt()** is a jQuery extension and not part of the CSS specification, queries using :gt() cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. **For better performance in modern browsers, use $("your-pure-css-selector").slice(index) instead.**

Comment: @MichaelGrigsby. It's a useless DEMO, but maybe you'll find it amusing... http://jsfiddle.net/PrFRP/2/

Answer (score 17):

CSS solution

```
ul li:nth-child(n+5) {  
    display: none
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mckanet/Sp6yE/

Comment: Needed pure CSS to hide some gallery images in a responsive design.  This worked.  Thanks!

Comment: pure CSS solution looks more cleaner +1

Answer (score 8):

As simple as that:

```
$("a:gt(3)").hide();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gmrvK/